# How to use a specific version of java in IE or Chrome

Tags: java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, version

This is my problem.
A dozen of users in my enterprise use an intranet web tool X using java and a java tool Y launched with .jar file.

X is compatible with java 1.6 but not compatible with java 1.7 
Y is compatible with java 1.7 but not compatible with java 1.6

Is there a way to manage this?
My idea was to instal java 1.6 & 1.7 on the PC and to force IE or Chrome to use the 1.6 version for the intranet web tool X. But I don't really know how to do that.

Maybe someone can help me here with that crazy problem !
Tx a lot.

Comment: The browsers take the java present in the system path. So i am not sure whether your design of switching between java version is possible. And the tool which works with java 7 should be compact able with 1.6 too, if it is properly developed. And most important is this question is not intended to be here. It should be in superuser.com or metastackExchange.com!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to configure a single web browser install to use two different versions of Java.  Furthermore, the version of Java used by a browser is controlled by the end user (or his admin).

So, your options are rather limited:

- Ditch one of the applications.
- Fix the older application so that it works on Java 7.
- Get your users to install two different browsers, and install Java plugins for / from different versions of Java in each one.  (For example: https://superuser.com/questions/45911/java-different-versions-for-ie-firefox ... though that is for a different pair of browsers.)

  The snag is that user than has to remember to use the right browser for each tool.

---

Frankly, if you can't upgrade the application that depends on Java 6, it is probably time to ditch it.  Java 6 has been end-of-lifed, and running it in a web browser is a significant security risk.